# How can I put the polyfill script and the css in the head and the vendor script before the app script in the body

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have the following entries: 
1. polyfill.ts
2. vendor.ts
3. app.ts

What I want:

1. The polyfill script in the head
2. the vendor script in the body
3. the app script in the body **after** the vendor script
4. the css, **referenced by the app script**, in the head.

As you can see I am doing a lot of manual stuff. The default inject is not adhering what I want. Note: What I have below does work.

**The question is:** Is what I do below the correct way to adhere what I want?

So these are the chunks I get: 
[image]

This is my webpack.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
        entry: {
            polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
            vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
            app: './src/app.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
            publicPath: './dist/'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }
                },
                [...]
                {
                    test: /\.(scss)$/,
                    use: extractSass.extract({
                        use: [{
                            loader: "css-loader"
                        }, {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader', // Run post css actions
                            options: {
                                plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                                    return [
                                        require('precss'),
                                        require('autoprefixer')
                                    ];
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            loader: "sass-loader"
                        }]
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                template: 'Views/Shared/_LayoutTemplate.cshtml',
                filename: '../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml',
                chunks: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'app'],
                heads: ['polyfills'],
                bodys: ['vendor', 'app']
            }),
            new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: ['app']
            }),
            extractSass
        ]
    };
```

This is my html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

        <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.heads) { %>
        <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[htmlWebpackPlugin.options.heads[chunk]].entry %>"></script>
        <% } %>

        <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys) { %>
            <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys[chunk]].css && htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys[chunk]].css.length !== 0) { %>
                <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys[chunk]].css %>" rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()

        <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys) { %>
        <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[htmlWebpackPlugin.options.bodys[chunk]].entry %>"></script>
        <% } %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm also working in .Net and trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: Eventually we dismissed our own webpack.config and let the Angular CLI eject their webpack config. Maybe wrong but we took the assumption that the guys from Angular did a good thought for this. Then we changed the HtmlWebpackPlugin so it would inject it in the cshtml template just in the body. note: the index.html that Angular CLI generates ALSO puts every thing in the body... and the styles are in the JS..